# Using a Bib file on VSCode with Latex Workshop enabled

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, bibtex

I am using VScode (macOS operating system) as a pseudo overleaf (trying to prevent connectivity issues). I am using a revtex template and want to use a bib file to hold all my references. For some reason the bib file is not parsing. When I save the bibtex file, the references I've entered just disappear.

This is the error that I get when I save my file:
"Bibtex parser failed with error: Expected ",", "=", "\r\n", [ \t\n], or [^@={}", \t\r\n] but "}" found."

I want to set up my VScode like overleaf, so if anyone has any simple solutions please do comment!

Below is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, reprint, showkeys, nofootinbib, twoside, aps, pra]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos, color=green!40, prependcaption]{todonotes}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=23mm,right=13mm,top=35mm,columnsep=15pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{csquotes}
% \usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[pdftex, pdftitle={Article}, pdfauthor={Author}]{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF
\def\bibsection{\section*{\refname}} % removes ugly line above bibliography
%\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2.5cm}
% \bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
% \addbibresource{LitReviewNotes.bib}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: You should add your bib file to the question. The error is related to the values inside that  file